# I want to compare the data I have in csv file to the data which is in ldap produciton server

Tags: csv, ldap

I want to compare the data I have in csv file to the data which is in ldap produciton server.

There are thousands of users data in csv file and i want to compare the data with the data in production server.

Let's suppose I have user ID xtz12345 in the csv file with uid number 123456. Now I want to cross check the uidNumber of the same user ID xtz12345 in the production server.

Is there any way I can automate this? There are thousands of UserID to be checked and if i do it manually it probably gonna take a lot of time. Can anyone suggest what should I do?

Comment: There are tools that allow you to query an LDAP server if you can bind to it. Find one that allows you to save the data and write a comparison. Or, write a query tool in PowerShell (for Windows) or PHP (for Linux) or some other language if you have one with an LDAP extension. As it stands, there's no programming content here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell script is good start place.

import activedirectory module (assuming Windows ADdownload and install RSAT tools, [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520)) in Powershell to fetch information from AD, [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

use import-csv in powershell to read csv values. Now, compare first with second. [example](https://techexpert.tips/powershell/powershell-read-lines-from-csv-file/#:%7E:text=In%20our%20example%2C%20we%20create%20a%20CSV%20file,a%20CSV%20file%20using%20the%20loop%20named%20FOREACH.)

Happy to help

Comment: All reasonable stuff if the OP is operating in a Windows Active Directory environment. Otherwise, largely useless.